# VBA RunTime Error 445 - Application.FileSearch

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, excel-2003

I have the same problem as the friend on this link:
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?503199-RESOLVED-Opening-an-excel-file-in-VB-without-the-exact-name&highlight=open%20file%20excel

Basically I would like to open a file, I know only a part of the file name, using VBA-Coding.

I found the webstie above with the potential solution but unfortunately, my compiler gives me Runtime Error 445

```
Sub openfile()
    Dim i As Integer
    With Application.FileSearch
        'Change the path to your path
        .LookIn = "C:\Temp"
        '* represents wildcard characters
        .FileName = "Sales_Report_1_4_2008*.xls"
        If .Execute > 0 Then 'Workbook exists
            'open all files that find the match
            For i = 1 To .FoundFiles.Count
                Workbooks.Open (.FoundFiles(i))
            Next i
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Could anyone help me to make this code work on Excek 2016??

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: You can try using Windows APIs like these:

apiFindFirstFile, apiFindNextFile, lpFindFileData
I have a couple of working VBA functions I can post if you are interested , but they are a bit longer and are for generic use - but you could work with them.

Comment: Hi Felix, I think it would be a nice idea to share oppertunities for the community :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `FileSearch` is discontinued.  May use File system Object. May add reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"  and try

```
Sub openfile()
    Dim Path As String
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim Fl  As File
    Dim Fld As Folder

    Path = "C:\temp\"
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Fld = oFSO.GetFolder(strPath)

    For Each Fl In Fld.Files
      If Ucase(Fl.Name) Like Ucase("Sales_Report_1_4_2008*.xls") Then
        Workbooks.Open (Fl.Path)
      End If
    Next Fl

    Set FSO = Nothing
    Set Fl = Nothing
    Set Fld = Nothing
End Sub
```

or even simpler loop through with `Dir` function

```
    Sub openfile()
        Dim Path As String
        Dim Fname As String

        Path = "C:\temp\"
        Fname = Dir(Path & "Sales_Report_1_4_2008*.xls")
        Do While Fname <> ""
           Workbooks.Open (Path & Fname)
        Fname = Dir
        Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ahmed. The first code is not working but the 2nd one with Dir function is working very well. But I would have another question. How can I change the code if i only know partial name in the middle of the file name? Forexample the file name is " 123_abc_458.xlsx" and what i know is only "abc" ??? This would help me a lot. Thanks in advance

Comment: In 1st code `Like` operator  is case sensitive, May use `Ucase` function on both Left & Right expressions of Like. If you only know partial name in the middle of the file name may use of wildcard like `*abc*.xls`