# Why is VBA in Excel asking for a Macro when I press run or F5?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA. Below is a code to check for new files in a folder and return new files.

```vba
SubCheck_for_new2()

  Dim vaFileName As Variant, lCnt As Long
  Const MyDir As String = "C:\Users\carolyntomasine\OneDrive - Li & Fung\Supply Chain Analyst\Item Setup Approvals"
  Const strMrk As String = "AL"
    
  With Application.FileSearch
    .NewSearch
    .LookIn = MyDir
    .SearchSubFolders = True
    .FileType = msoFileTypeOfficeFiles
    If .Execute > 0 Then
      lCnt = 0
      For Each vaFileName In .FoundFiles
        If Right(Left(vaFileName, Len(vaFileName) - 4), 2) <> strMrk Then
          lCnt = lCnt + 1
          Sheet1.Cells(lCnt, 1).Value = vaFileName
        End If
      Next
      If lCnt = 0 Then MsgBox "There were no new Office files found."
    Else
      MsgBox "There were no Office files found."
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

However, when I press. run, it prompts me for Macro name. May I know why? And what is the solution?

Comment: It may be something as simple as 'Sub Check_For_New2' vs your 'SubCheck_For_New2'
Make sure you put Option Explicit as the start of each code module/class/form.  You could also install the free and fantastic open source Rubberduck addin for VBA and take a look at the code inspections.

Comment: Thank you! But now, a different error is returned. .Lookin = MyDir is highlighted and there is "Compile error: Constant expression required".

Comment: @Carolyn that would be a new question, with all its supporting information.

Comment: BTW `Application.FileSearch` does not work in version 2007 and newer.

Comment: Is there an equitable alternative for newer versions?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.filedialog

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54725018/vba-runtime-error-445-application-filesearch